# Check if a cell substring is numeric

Tags: excel-2010

I have a cell that should contain values like 123456789WA. The first 9 characters should always be numbers, and the last 2 should be WA. I can check the length to make sure it's 11, I can check the last two characters to make sure they're "WA", but I can't figure out how to check the first 9 to make sure they're numbers. ISNUMBER doesn't work because the cell is text, so it always gives a false. Here's my cell formula:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)<>11,"Not 11 char",IF(RIGHT(A2,2)<>"WA","Missing 'WA'",IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(A2,9)),"","Left not numeric")))
```

I can do it in VBA, but this is something I'm passing off to very unsophisticated users, so I need to make it work in a cell. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a value in **A1**, the first 9 characters can be tested with:

```
=IF(ISERROR(--LEFT(A1,9)),"not all numbers","all numbers")
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! Works like a charm.